# Elasticsearch (7.3) date mapping parsing failures

Tags: date, elasticsearch, indexing, lucene

I have upgraded elasticsearch from 6.2.3 to 7.3

The mapping in ES looks like this:

```
"completion_date" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "store" : true,
          "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ||yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ||yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
```

Failing with bellow exception:

Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=failed to parse field [completion_date] in document ....4181937'. Preview of field's value: '2018-01-23T16:40:00.000Z']

Could you please help me, explain why does it happen, and how I could fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you, i tried it and noticed that it works in ES6 but not in ES7. However, it seems to work if you put the following format :

```
"format" : "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

But i don't think it is the best solution since it is not specified like this in the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/mapping-date-format.html) (maybe they will update it later).
For me, the best solution is to call the format with their name, as specified in the documentation : [es doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.4/mapping-date-format.html)

So your mapping should look something like this :

```
"completion_date" : {
      "type" : "date",
      "store" : true,
      "format" : "strict_date_time||strict_date_time_no_millis||strict_date"
    }
```

Hope that helps!